# how to configure items per page value in properties file

Tags: alfresco-share

how to configure items per page value dynamically(preferably in the properties file).presently 50 is hard coded in the respective js files.Do we need to do any customization to set this value in properties?if yes how to do the customization?

using alfresco 4.2.2 version.

pageSize:50

for document library

---

C:\tomcat\webapps\share\components\documentlibrary\documentlist.js

for search

---

C:\tomcat\webapps\share\components\search\search.js

Answer (score 0):

In Alfresco 5.2, if you want to config number of items per page in Document Library, the steps are the following:

1.- Copy the file "documentlist-v2.get.js" to "D:\alfresco-community-5-2\tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension\site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\documentlibrary"

2.- In this file we have to add the following line:
`model.widgets[1].options.pageSize = 10;`

3.- We will add this line at the end of the code of widgets function:

```
function widgets()
{
   var useTitle = "true";
   var docLibConfig = config.scoped["DocumentLibrary"];
   if (docLibConfig != null)
   {
      var tmp = docLibConfig["use-title"];
      useTitle = tmp != null ? tmp : "true";
   }

   var docListToolbar = {
      id: "DocListToolbar", 
      name: "Alfresco.DocListToolbar",
      assignTo: "docListToolbar",
      options: {
         siteId: (page.url.templateArgs.site != null) ? page.url.templateArgs.site : "",
         rootNode: toolbar.rootNode != null ? toolbar.rootNode : "",
         repositoryRoot: toolbar.rootNode,
         hideNavBar: Boolean(toolbar.preferences.hideNavBar),
         repositoryBrowsing: toolbar.rootNode != null,
         useTitle: (useTitle == "true"),
         syncMode: toolbar.syncMode != null ? toolbar.syncMode : "",
         createContentByTemplateEnabled: model.createContentByTemplateEnabled,
         createContentActions: model.createContent
      }
   };

   var documentList = {
      id : "DocumentList", 
      name : "Alfresco.DocumentList",
      options : {
         syncMode : model.syncMode != null ? model.syncMode : "",         
         siteId : (page.url.templateArgs.site != null) ? page.url.templateArgs.site : "",
         containerId : template.properties.container != null ? template.properties.container : "documentLibrary",
         rootNode : model.rootNode != null ? model.rootNode : "null",
         repositoryRoot : model.rootNode,
         usePagination : (args.pagination == "true"),
         sortAscending : (model.preferences.sortAscending != null ? model.preferences.sortAscending : true),
         sortField : model.preferences.sortField != null ? model.preferences.sortField : "cm:name",
         showFolders : (model.preferences.showFolders != null ? model.preferences.showFolders : true),
         hideNavBar: (model.preferences.hideNavBar != null ? model.preferences.hideNavBar : false),
         simpleView : model.preferences.simpleView != null ? model.preferences.simpleView : "null",
         viewRenderers: model.viewRenderers,
         viewRendererName : model.preferences.viewRendererName != null ? model.preferences.viewRendererName : "detailed",
         viewRendererNames : model.viewRendererNames != null ? model.viewRendererNames : ["simple", "detailed", "gallery", "filmstrip"],
         highlightFile : page.url.args["file"] != null ? page.url.args["file"] : "",
         replicationUrlMapping : model.replicationUrlMapping != null ? model.replicationUrlMapping : "{}",
         repositoryBrowsing : model.rootNode != null, 
         useTitle : (model.useTitle != null ? model.useTitle == "true" : true),
         userIsSiteManager : model.userIsSiteManager,
         associatedToolbar: { _alfValue: "docListToolbar", _alfType: "REFERENCE" },
         commonComponentStyle : model.commonComponentStyle,
         suppressComponent : model.suppressComponent,
         filmstripImageLazyLoading: model.filmstripImageLazyLoading == "true"
      }
   };
   if (model.repositoryUrl != null)
   {
      documentList.options.repositoryUrl = model.repositoryUrl;
   }

   model.widgets = [docListToolbar, documentList];
   **model.widgets[1].options.pageSize = 10;**
}
```

4.- In this case we have establish ten items per page

5.- We must restart Alfresco Service and after that this configuration will be available

Regards,
[image]